# Trying to get rvm to work, but getting error running

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

I get the following Error when running rvm reinstall 1.9.3, I followed some advice to deleted these files and folders below, now I dont have them even after removing rvm and reinstalling with curl, what do I do? I used the rails installer, and I think that is what has messed this whole thing up. I just want to start from scratch.

```
rm -rf /opt/sm 
rm /etc/rvmrc
rm /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
```

I also get this output when trying to install rvm reinstall 1.9.3

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3
Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385...
Removing /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385...
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p385.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
Extracting yaml to /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
Configuring yaml in /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/usr --disable-shared', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/yaml/make.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p385, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p385 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr --disable-shared', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

PLEASE help this has been taking me forever, to figure this out.

make.log

```
[2013-02-11 21:27:46] make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Check the content of `/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/yaml/configure.log` as indicated by the first error message. Good idea to gist it somewhere; the file is likely to be huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after removing the files you need also open new terminal - if it does not help -  restart computer

Comment: I am going to choose this as the accepted answer, but instead of restarting I just restored my machine, I needed to anyways.